# Сортировка объектов по полю в ArrayList

Tags: java

У меня есть коллекция объектов, которая внутри себя содержит также коллекцию объектов, которые требуется отсортировать в алфавитном порядке по имени поля `name`. Каким способом лучше это всего сделать, через стримы я смог отсортировать только внешние объекты, но как подобраться к внутренним не понятно.

Прикладываю скрин структуры объектов. Соответственно, нужна сортировка только коллекции `members`. Подскажите, каким способом это лучше всего сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE:**

```
public class SmbpStructUserType extends SmbpUserType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Members")
    MembersList membersList = new MembersList();

    public boolean addMember(Member member) {
        return membersList.members.add(member);
    }

    public List<Member> getMembers() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(membersList.members);
    }

    static class MembersList {
        @XmlElement(name = "Member")
        List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static class Member {

        private String name;


        private long userTypeId;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @XmlAttribute(name = "Name", required = true)
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public long getUserTypeId() {
            return userTypeId;
        }
        @XmlAttribute(name = "UserTypeId", required = true)
        public void setUserTypeId(long userTypeId) {
            this.userTypeId = userTypeId;
        }
    }
}
```

Добавление элементов:

```
Map<Integer, SmbpStructUserType> structUserTypeMap = new HashMap<>();

        jdbcTemplate.query(queryForGetStructUserTypes, resultSet -> {
            SmbpStructUserType smbpStructUserType = structUserTypeMap.computeIfAbsent(userTypeId, p -> {
                SmbpStructUserType userType = new SmbpStructUserType();
                userType.setId(userTypeId);
                userType.setName(typeName);
                userType.setNamespace(namespace);
                userType.setDescription(description);
                return userType;
            });

            SmbpStructUserType.Member member = new SmbpStructUserType.Member();
            member.setName(resultSet.getString("MemberName"));
            member.setUserTypeId(resultSet.getLong("MemberUserTypeId"));
            smbpStructUserType.addMember(member);
        }, UserTypeKind.STRUCT.getId());
```

Comment: Обойти внешнюю коллекцию циклом и отсортировать каждый элемент.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, а как после сортировки внутренней коллекции закинуть ее во внешнюю с заменой несортированной?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashMap`? Которая внутри содержит коллекцию? У вас формулировка идет вразрез с тем, что на скриншотике и в коде.

**Обновил ответ**

Для того, чтобы отсортировать (по полю `name`) объекты `Member` внутри коллекций `members`, которые в свою очередь находятся в объектах `MembersList` которые находятся в объектах `SmbpStructUserType`, вам нужно сделать вот так:

```
structUserTypeMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
    v.membersList.members.sort(Comparator.comparing(m -> m.name));        
});
```

Что делаю:

Проходим-пробегаем по мапе `structUserTypeMap`, из каждого ее `value` берем `membersList.members` - `ArrayList`. На этой коллекции вызываем метод `sort`, передавая компаратор, который будет сравнивать объекты `Member` по их полю `name`. Коллекция отсортирована в том месте, где и была. И все довольны!

Если брать `values`:

```
values = structUserTypeMap.values();

values.forEach(v -> {
    v.membersList.members.sort(Comparator.comparing(m -> m.name));        
});
```

В способе с потоками (`stream`) создаются временные наборы элементов, а исходные остаются нетронутыми, поэтому тут потоки я не использовал.

**Однако** с точки зрения читаемости кода, да и в целом как хороший тон, вам стоило бы инкапсулировать вашу сортировку внутри, скажем, вашего `SmbpStructUserType`:

```
public void sortMembers() {
    // логика сортировки тут
}
```

Чтобы потом можно было просто и понятно сортировать всю карту:

```
structUserTypeMap.forEach((k, v) -> v.sortMembers());
```

А для `values` еще приятнее:

```
values.forEach(SmbpStructUserType::sortMembers);
```

Comment: фишка в том, что данный способ сортирует все `name`, но они то привязаны к определенному внешнему объекту

Comment: @All_Safe не понимаю, о каком внешнем объекте вы говорите. Я сортировал вам не `все name`, а все объекты `Member` в коллекции `members` **по полю** `name`.

Comment: добавил код в вопрос. из `SmbpStructUserType` я беру `values()`

Comment: @All_Safe проясним то, что вы хотите. Вам нужно отсортировать все коллекции `members`, которые находятся внутри вот этого всего по полю `name`? При этом вам ничего не нужно сортировать в базе данных

Comment: да, все верно. Нужно отсортировать лист `members`, который находится внутри `SmbpStructUserType`. Из базы я только получаю эти данные

Comment: @All_Safe смотрите ответ, я обновил

Comment: получается что коллекция у меня не изменяемая `Collections.unmodifiableList(membersList.members);` и сортировку я применить не смогу. А если я создам новый экземпляр листа, то сортировка работать не будет

Comment: @All_Safe У вас ведь лишь метод `getMembers` возвращает неизменяемый экземпляр коллекции. Сама коллекция `members` вполне себе изменяемая. Правда она у вас без модификатора доступа `package-private`, так что вы не отовсюду сможете обратиться к этому полю. Но там, где сможете, сортировка вполне будет работать

Comment: еще такой вопрос. Насколько правильно инкапсулировать логику сортировки (`sortMembers()`) внутри обычного `POJO`?

Comment: @All_Safe вполне себе правильно. У вас данные не просто валяются, а сокрыты в объект. Почему бы не сделать работу с этими данными в самом объекте? Я не эксперт в данной теме, но точно вам скажу: чем ближе друг к другу (к примеиу, в одном классе) будут находиться данные и их обработка - тем лучше.