# помогите сортировкой массива с помощью лямбды

Tags: массивы, сортировка, java-8, lambda

есть класс студент, есть поля имя, курс, дата рождения, есть массив этого студента надо отсортировать с помощью лямбды!

```
public class D {

    Student[] students = {new Student("Petya", 1, 14),
                                new Student("Vasya", 2, 20),
                                new Student("Igor", 4, 13)};


    public void sortStudent() {

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(students));//до сортировки

        Arrays.sort(students);

    }

}
```

Comment: А по какому полю?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сортировка объектов по полю в ArrayList](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763324/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d0%b2-arraylist)